# How to vertically center text in a List containing an image

Tags: html, css

I'm starting in CSS and I can't figure out if it is possible to **vertically center** a text in an **unordered list** when it **contains an Image**.

I want to place a logo in my navbar ul and center the text but it sticks to the bottom of the Ul.

**Heres the code and what I want:**
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ViusX/69ovpxt4/6/)

[Image showing what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtWSO.jpg)

HTML:

```
<body>
    <header>
        <nav id="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><b><a href="index.html"><img class="logo" src="https://i28.servimg.com/u/f28/09/04/03/75/a_2_li10.png" alt="HOME"></a></b></li>
                <li><b><a href="more.html">MORE</a></b></li>
                <li><b><a href="services.html">SERVICES</a></b></li>
                <li><b><a href="blog.html">BLOG</a></b></li>
                <li><b><a href="shop.html">SHOP</a></b></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #294F6D;
    margin: 0;
}

#navbar ul {
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background-color:  #303E73;
    text-align: center;

}

#navbar li {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #A13647;
    padding: 20px 50px
}

.logo {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is `vertical-align: middle;`.

You can just add it to your CSS here:

```
#navbar li {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #A13647;
    padding: 20px 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Here's a working example:

```css
body {

    background-color: #294F6D;
    margin: 0;
}

#navbar ul {
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background-color:  #303E73;
    text-align: center;

}

#navbar li {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #A13647;
    padding: 20px 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.logo {
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <nav id="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><b><a href="index.html"><img class="logo" src="https://i28.servimg.com/u/f28/09/04/03/75/a_2_li10.png" alt="HOME"></a></b></li>
                <li><b><a href="more.html">MORE</a></b></li>
                <li><b><a href="services.html">SERVICES</a></b></li>
                <li><b><a href="blog.html">BLOG</a></b></li>
                <li><b><a href="shop.html">SHOP</a></b></li>
            </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Guess I over-engineered here. Well played!

Answer (score 1):

`display: flex` is your friend here:

```css
body {
  background-color: #294F6D;
  margin: 0;
}

#navbar ul {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color:  #303E73;
  text-align: center;

}

#navbar li {
  background-color: #A13647;
  padding: 20px 50px
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color:white;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.logo {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <nav id="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><b><a href="index.html"><img class="logo" src="https://i28.servimg.com/u/f28/09/04/03/75/a_2_li10.png" alt="HOME"></a></b></li>
                <li><b><a href="more.html">MORE</a></b></li>
                <li><b><a href="services.html">SERVICES</a></b></li>
                <li><b><a href="blog.html">BLOG</a></b></li>
                <li><b><a href="shop.html">SHOP</a></b></li>
            </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Check out [Flexbox on caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), as it still has a few edge-case issues in Internet Explorer. This example should work fine though.

Comment: Thanks, I also added     
    justify-content: center;

Comment: I suggest you mark the other answer by @SWC as your solution. It's way simpler and probably _the_ go-to solution to this specific request.

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
    background-color: #294F6D;
    margin: 0;
}

#navbar ul {
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #303E73;
    /* text-align: center; */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#navbar li {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #A13647;
    padding: 20px 50px;
}
#navbar li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
}
.logo {
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <nav id="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><b><a href="index.html"><img class="logo" src="https://i28.servimg.com/u/f28/09/04/03/75/a_2_li10.png" alt="HOME"></a></b></li>
                <li><b><a href="more.html">MORE</a></b></li>
                <li><b><a href="services.html">SERVICES</a></b></li>
                <li><b><a href="blog.html">BLOG</a></b></li>
                <li><b><a href="shop.html">SHOP</a></b></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
```

Comment: Best answer to me. :-)